# state not being set, and when it does its not correct

Tags: reactjs, axios, state, react-hooks

When i upload the first image, nothing is written to formData, however when i upload a second image, it uploads to "image" value and then the third upload will write to the "image2" value. Its like everything is one behind. If i ignore this and keep adding in info and finally submit "image2, image3,image4, and image5" values are not passed along.

Any help counts. Thanks!

```
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        year: "",
        make: "",
        model: "",
        price: "",
        image: "",
        image2: "",
        image3: "",
        image4: "",
        image5: "",
        hull: "",
        title: "",
        details: ""
      });

      const {
        year,
        make,
        model,
        price,
        image,
        image2,
        image3,
        image4,
        image5,
        hull,
        title,
        details
      } = formData;

      const types = ["image/png", "image/jpeg"];
      const [file, setFile] = useState("");
      const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");

    const onChange = e => {
            setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
          };

          const onImageChange = async e => {
            e.persist();
            console.log(formData);
            const data = new FormData();
            let file = e.target.files[0];
            console.log(file);
            data.append("file", file);

            try {
              const res = await axios.post("/api/upload", data, {
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
                }
              });

              const { fileName, filePath } = res.data;
              console.log(e.target.name);
              console.log(filePath);
              setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: res.data.filePath});


            } catch (err) {
              console.log("fileUpload Err");
              console.log(err);
            }
          };

          return (
            <div className="posts_area">
              <form
                className="post_form"
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  addPost({
                    year,
                    make,
                    model,
                    price,
                    image,
                    image2,
                    image3,
                    image4,
                    image5,
                    hull,
                    title,
                    details
                  });
                }}
              >
                <h5 className="create-post-title">Boat Year:</h5>
                <input
                  name="year"
                  value={year}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  placeholder="Year"
                  className="create_post_fields"
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Make:</h5>
                <input
                  name="make"
                  value={make}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  placeholder="Make"
                  className="create_post_fields"
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Model:</h5>
                <input
                  name="model"
                  value={model}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  placeholder="Model"
                  className="create_post_fields"
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Price:</h5>
                <input
                  name="price"
                  value={price}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  placeholder="Price"
                  className="create_post_fields"
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Hull Type:</h5>
                <input
                  name="hull"
                  value={hull}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  placeholder="Hull Type"
                  className="create_post_fields"
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Add a title to your post:</h5>
                <input
                  name="title"
                  value={title}
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  placeholder="Title"
                  className="create_post_fields"
                  required
                />
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Other Details:</h5>
                <textarea
                  placeholder="Ex. Has freshwater tank"
                  name="details"
                  onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                  className="create_post_fields"
                ></textarea>
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Upload Main Image</h5>
                <input type="file" name="image" onChange={ev => onImageChange(ev)} />
                <br />
                <br />

                <h5 className="create-post-title">Upload Secondary Images</h5>
                <input type="file" name="image2" onChange={ev => onImageChange(ev)} />
                <br />
                <br />

                <input type="file" name="image3" onChange={ev => onImageChange(ev)} />
                <br />
                <br />

                <input type="file" name="image4" onChange={ev => onImageChange(ev)} />
                <br />
                <br />

                <input type="file" name="image5" onChange={ev => onImageChange(ev)} />
                <br />
                <br />


                <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="submit_button" />
              </form>
            </div>
          );
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `setFormData(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));` instead.

Comment: if i switch ..prev and prev, it likes it alot better but i get an error at :

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was updating the formData but the console.log wasnt being updated fast enough? I ran a console.log at the top of each onImageChange and you could see it update after each run that way. Super weird